# remove 3 last divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, dom-traversal

```
<div id="widgetAreaFooter">
<div class="row">1</div>
<div class="row">2</div>
<div class="row">3</div>
<div class="row">4</div>
<div class="row">5</div>
<div class="row">6</div>
<div class="row">7</div>
</div>
```

How to remove the 3 last div ?

I tryed this but it doesn't work :/

```
var row = $( '#widgetAreaFooter>.row' );
var nbr = row.length ;

for ( var i=4;i<nbr;i++ ) row.get(i).remove();
or
for ( var i=4;i<nbr;i++ ) row[i].remove();
```

Comment: I guess the code you supplied only removed row 5 and 7. You also needed to i-- after (or during) removal: `$(row[i--]).remove();`. However @bazmegakapa's is clearer and safer. **Edit:** my mistake. You should also decrease nbr after removing the item. As I said, @bazmegakapa had the best solution.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This will remove the last three elements:

```
$('#widgetAreaFooter > .row').slice(-3).remove();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nTeAY/)

- You can get a part of a jQuery collection using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

  > If a negative number is provided,
  >   this indicates a position starting
  >   from the end of the set, rather than
  >   the beginning.