# How to remove last element from div?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have list of descriptions and after remove one of them, I'd like to remove last element from div, not refreshing site. I don't know javascript in fact, so I'd like to ask how should my destroy.js.erb looks like? I can refresh whole class "descriptions" using

```
$('.descriptions').load(location.href + " .descriptions");
```

but I'm interested, if there is way to remove only last element.

```
  <div class="descriptions">
       <%= render @descriptions %> 
  </div>

 //_description.html.erb
 <div class="description-field">
        <%= @description.text %>
 </div>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: $('.descriptions').last().remove() ??

Comment: It removes whole div too

Comment: `document.querySelector('.descriptions > :last-child').remove();`? (For recent browsers, and assuming you only have one `.descriptions` element)

Comment: @adolzi, as others are suggesting, you can use `:last-child`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        Item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

The following line of jQuery would delete "Item 3."

```
$('.parent').children().last().remove();
```

Comment: What if we want to delete more than one children from bottom?

Comment: I found this thread, which seems like it answers your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623445/remove-3-last-divs-with-jquery

Comment: How would I delete the parent div?

Comment: Hey, just $('.parent').remove(); would work for the example above. However, removing the parent would also remove all children contained in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use css selector `:last-child` to remove it (found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp)). Then use jQuery to remove last element.

```
$(".yourdiv :last-child").remove();
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fut7zkty/) example:

html:

```
<div>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <p> World </p>
    <p> last element </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("div :last-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to remove the last div:

```
$("div:last").remove();
```

Use this if you want to remove the last sibling of some div with id "#mydiv"

```
$('#mydiv:last-child')
```

Comment: Misunderstanding of `:last-child`. Maybe this article about [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) helps you. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div id="child">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div id="child">
        Item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is a JQuery code that removes the last child item 3

```
$("#child").remove();
```

or you can also use

```
$("#child").css({"display": "none"});
```

Comment: This is just wrong. First, `.remove()` removes all matched elements, so it would remove every child, BUT your example markup is also invalid (multiple same IDs) and even in this case it's not correct, as it removes only the first child then.